# Adjacent rollover buttons: only last button shows. Why?

Tags: html, css

Making one rollover button works. The rollover buttons are correctly made using Photoshop (split upper and lower image). An example: https://www.studio61.be/home-en.html#tarieven
However, when I want to have three adjacent (left float) buttons in one div, only the last one shows. The two invisible buttons do work when hover above them, but they don't show up.
What is wrong?

HTML:

```
<div id="talen">
    <p class="taal-en"><a href="home-en.html">Klik hier<span>Welcome</span></a></p>
    <p class="taal-fr"><a href="home-fr.html">Klik hier<span>Bienvenu</span></a></p>
    <p class="taal-nl"><a href="index.html">Klik hier<span>Welkom</span></a></p>
    
     </div>
```

CSS:

```
.taal-nl {
    display:block;
    width:75px;
    height:25px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    float: left;
}
.taal-nl a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    outline:none;
    background: transparent url(../images/buttons/welkom_v3.gif) no-repeat left top;
    float: left;
}
.taal-nl a:hover {
    background-position:0 -25px;
}
.taal-en {
    display:block;
    width:75px;
    height:25px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    float: left;
}
.taal-en a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    outline:none;
    background: transparent url(../images/buttons/welcome_v3.gif) no-repeat left top;
    float: left;
}
.taal-en a:hover {
    background-position:0 -25px;
}
.taal-fr {
    display:block;
    width:75px;
    height:25px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    float: left;
}
.taal-fr a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    outline:none;
    background: transparent url(../images/buttons/bienvenu_v3.gif) no-repeat left top;
    float: left;
}
.taal-fr a:hover {
    background-position:0 -25px;
}
```

Comment: You should provide a link to some demo so people can view and play with it. You can explore platforms like CodePen, JSFiddle, or CodeSandbox

Comment: Great, I did not know that, I will explore these platforms

Answer (score 0):

I have just added a different background image to your button, and now it is working perfectly fine.

See your working code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-pqmygn?file=index.html)

I think there is some issue with your background image path, either the path is wrong or the image in not available there. Last button is showing because you have used different image path for last button.

Comment: I had solved the issue, tried to edit my post, but "edit mode" has not yet updated my post.
I had forgotten to upload the first two images.

Comment: @Erik84750 Ohh, that's what I pointed, that means my answer was right, kindly accept the answer by clicking accept button below voting. Thanks. Happy coding... :)